# How not to audit a join table and related entities using Hibernate Envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I use Hibernate Envers to audit my entities.

I have one audited entity, `Foo`, which has a `List<Bar>` as properties. However, I don't want to audit the `Bar` entities. Thus, I wrote that:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Foo {

    @JoinTable(name = "T_FOO_BAR", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID"))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = PERSIST)
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

}
```

Now, I want to retrieve a revision of `Foo`:

```
    AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(getEntityManager());
    Foo revision = (Foo) reader.createQuery().forEntitiesAtRevision(Foo.class, 42).getSingleResult();
```

Unfortunately, when I want to retrieve all the data (i.e. when it lazy loads the `bars`), I get the error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`, as it tried to query:

```
select ... from T_FOO_BAR_AUD x, T_BAR y where ...
```

I though that using `@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)`, Hibernate Envers would keep the links with the `Bar` items of the *current* entity.

So how can I solve my problem, without having to explicitely audit the tables `T_BAR` and `T_FOO_BAR` (the join table)? In others words, when I retrieve the list of `bars` from my revision entity, I get the list of `bars` from my current entity (as the links between `Foo` and `Bar` are not audited).

Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you're using `@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)` when you should be using `@NotAudited` in your case.

`RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED` will simply not audit the **target entity**.  It will still try to audit the `List<Bar>` property of `Foo`, and thus the join table.

From the docs:

> If you want to audit a relation, where the target entity is not
>   audited (that is the case for example with dictionary-like entities,
>   which don't change and don't have to be audited), just annotate it
>   with `@Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)`.
>   Then, when reading historic versions of your entity, the relation will
>   always point to the "current" related entity.